# What is a proper subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the $5$'th root of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Using Galois theory, I know there is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, but I cannot think of which one it is, since every power of $\alpha$ i.e. ($\alpha^j$) where $j \in [1,5]$ one can obtain $\alpha$ again through field operations.

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: Take the subfield $\Bbb Q(\zeta+\overline{\zeta})$ fixed by conjugation. The degree is $[\Bbb Q(\zeta):\Bbb Q(\zeta+\overline{\zeta})]=2$, with minimal polynomial $x^2-(\zeta+\overline{\zeta})x+1$. Note that $[\Bbb Q(\zeta):\Bbb Q]=\phi(5)=4$.

Comment: Another way to get the same field: $\mathbb Q(\alpha)\cap\mathbb R$.